# How can I check the result of Google "AutoML" table?

Tags: report, automl

I used Google AutoML table.
I got some result from that, but I don't know how can I check the result specifically.
I want to know such as...
What kinds of models and which model showed the best result.
How may parameters and layers used.
Hyperparameter tuning,
etc

## For example,
Google AutoML showed several models which they tried as below, but I couldn't fine which one was the best.

"hyperparameters":
{"Normalize numerical column": "True",
"Model type": "nn",
"Skip connections type": "concat",
"Number of cross layers": "1",
"Enable layerNorm": "False",
"Enable embedding L2": "False",
"Enable L2": "False",
"Hidden layer size": 256,
"Dropout rate": 0.5,
"Enable embedding L1": "False",
"Embedding numerical embedding": "True",
"Number of hidden layers": "2",
"Enable batchNorm": "False",
"Enable L1": "False"

Please, let me know how can I get more specific result report?